# Insert PHP variable in dynamic html

Tags: php, html, forms, dynamic, controller

I am trying to create HTML page dynamically within php controller. This is the part of code

```
$body .= ' <form method="get">
               <input type="hidden" name="leave" value=<?php echo "$id">> 
               <input type="submit" value="Leave">
           </form>';
```

It creates button with text "Leave" and I need to pass an ID with GET/POST request to work with it in another function. Is it possible to do it this way?

I tried a few stackoverflow pages but none of that worked. Here is what my log says:

```
[Sun Nov 20 16:43:37 2022] id in _GET: <?php
```

Comment: Compare https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php .

Answer (score 3):

The code you're showing already is running PHP. No need to put the `<?php ?>` inside PHP code. To insert the variable's value into the string, just append it.

```php
$body .= ' <form method="get">
               <input type="hidden" name="leave" value='.$id.'> 
               <input type="submit" value="Leave">
           </form>';
```

Additionally - the error you're getting is because you didn't properly close the `<?php`. As can be seen in the code, you end it with `>` instead of `?>`.

```php
<input type="hidden" name="leave" value=<?php echo "$id"; ?>>
                                start --^               ^ ^- missing question mark
                                                        `-- missing semicolon
```

Comment: Yeah that's it, thank you. I was trying to do it many ways and I also tried it with the question mark, but I didn't notice I copied it without it.